# Revert default finder

Tags: terminal, finder

I used this command to try out an alternative finder.

`defaults write com.apple.loginwindow Finder /Full/Path/To/Path\ Finder.app`

I prefer the standard finder - but do not know how to get it back.

Anybody know?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know. But I bet you can do both

```
defaults delete com.apple.loginwindow Finder
```

or

```
defaults write com.apple.loginwindow Finder /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app
```